# laravel repository - why need to call to interface instead of calling directly to repository file?

Tags: php, laravel, interface, repository

I've read about repository pattern.So, I created `UserRepositoryInterface.php` file

```php
namespace App\Interfaces;

use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\RepositoryInterface;

interface UserInterface extends RepositoryInterface
{
    // Code
}
```

Then I created `UserRepository.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository;
use App\Interfaces\UserInterface;

class UserRepository extends BaseRepository implements UserInterface
{
    public function model()
    {
        return User::class;
    }
}
```

Finally, I bind interface to class in `RepositoryServiceProvider.php`

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind(UserInteface::class, UserRepository::class);
    }
```

When inject repository to class, I wonder that should I inject with `UserRepository` or `UserInterface`. I've read that `UserInterface` should be injected, but I don't understand why we not just using `UserRepository`, it can be faster, isn't it?
Someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of injecting interface instead concrete class is to have it easier for `change/extend/maintenance/test`.

Now, in your case here, you have injected  `UserRepositoryInterface` in some controller method or constructor let's say. But `UserRepository` class is still tightly coupled to Eloquent's code (since it's extending Eloquent's class).

Now imagine you are getting users from another provider/source (maybe from 3rd party through API call). That code you can set in separate class `\App\Repositories\ApiCallUserRepository` (for instance).

You would also set `ApiCallUserRepository` (newly created class) to implement `\App\Interfaces\UserInterface`.

When you have all of this, only change you should make is change in provider
or in other words you would just need to instruct application which concrete class to use when interface has been injected dependently. Also, this means that same structure of data should be provided from both concrete classes (repository providers) to class that uses repository (i.e. controller's method), or at least receiving data class/code should expect providing structure whether it was Eloquent Collection whether it's some other type of collection.

This way you have nicely set service that gets users for example. And you can easily choose from which provider you want to get users.

It's not all: in time of execution (i.e. when request is made) you can set appropriate concrete class or make additional code regarding by any arbitrary rules. In Laravel's service container check `when()->needs()->give()` but also I warmly recommend you to go again through full (page) [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/container).

Also don't limit yourself, but go through other generic and specific articles about DI:

[php-di](https://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html)

[designpatternsphp](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/DependencyInjection/README.html)

[Symfony DependencyInjection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html)

[laminas-di](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-di/)

Maybe all of this seems like overhead but in reality it is a good starting position for extending application in good, standard, maintainable, and testable way.

Comment: Sorry for lately reply and thanks for your answer. According to your answer, I can understand that I inject interface instead of class for testing purpose and being easier for changing class. Is that right? And with time of execution, I've read laravel document about ```Container Service``` but I still don't understand how ```Contextual Binding``` involve to time of execution. Do I miss something?

Comment: Not just only for testing purpose. But code written that way will give you more freedom in testing, correct. Since you can use different classes in. testing environment. (i.e. you can easy change DB config or cache config in tests).
Example in docs is pretty clear. Also check [Contracts page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/contracts) (which is PHP interfaces and dependency injection over interfaces page). To have contextual binding working in place you need to pass certain interface/contract (that's been bound in Provider class) to controller's (or any class where should be used) constructor.

Comment: totally understand with your reference link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, using repositories with Eloquent is just wasting time. With `ActiveRecord` all logic for storing and receiving data is already implemented within models. You just DON'T need another class and interface to call `User::all()`. This is just good example of over engineering.